# Barra de rolagem em um SELECT no html

Tags: html, css

Fala galera,
Tenho um SELECT em meu HTML que quando os resultados ultrapassam o limite do width, ele quebra uma linha. Eu gostaria que ao invés de quebrar essa linha, fosse adicionado uma barra de rolagem.

**Imagem explicativa:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[PÁGINA DE DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://b2bi.com.br/B2BI2017/app/demo.html)

Quais propriedades do css eu devo utilizar?
grato, um grande abraço!

Comment: Olá Caio, poderia postar como está seu código?

Comment: Adicionei uma página para demonstração.

Comment: Mas coloca o código, fica mais fácil de ajustar... Provavelmente terá de ser com javascript...Edita e adiciona a tag javascript também...

Comment: Caio, o seu problema é com o select2, que você está utilizando. Você não mencionou isso no início, e se editar agora você irá invalidar as respostas. Aconselho você a escolher uma que acha que te atenda melhor, e criar uma outra pergunta especificando o uso do plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar `overflow-x` e `white-space: nowrap;`, note que os elementos tem que usar `display: inline-block;`, eu acredito que isto não funcione com `float`, então remova-o dos seus elementos.

No caso do seu código ficaria assim (que usa o [Select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)):

```
/* itens dentro do select2 */
.select2-selection--multiple .select2-search--inline {
    float: none;/*"remove" o float*/
    display: inline-block;
}

/* área para digitar dentro do select2 */
.select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* área aonde ficam os items e o campo para digitar */
.select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__rendered {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Um exemplo para ver o efeito (e que será útil a futuros visitantes da pergunta)

```css
.area {
   border: 1px #ccc solid;
   padding: 5px;
   width: 400px;
   overflow-x: auto;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
.area > .item {
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #455a64;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 0 2px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fff;
}
.area > .item:last-child {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="area">
    <div class="item">
        Memes
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Programação
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Entretenimento
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Stack Overflow
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Super User
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Stack Exchange
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        C#
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        asp.net
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        asp.net-mvc
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: você é um monstro, valeu amigo!

Comment: é do monstros S/O lol...

Answer (score 3):

O `input` propriamente dito eu desconheço, mas você pode usar o `textarea`:

```css
textarea
{
    height:30px;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    resize: none;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

```html
<textarea>fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh</textarea>
```

**edit**

Como mencionado pelo @Felipe Nascimento, não é possível colocar elementos demtro do `input` e nem no `textarea` por serem  #PCDATA (processed character data). Aí vai ter de usar uma `div` mesmo...

Answer (score 2):

Tente utilizar esta propriedade CSS:

```
overflow-x: auto;
```

Coloque no elemento pai dessas div's, fará com que o scroll aparece horizontalmente se necessário, lembrando que esse mesmo elemento pai
deve ter o `height` definido.

Referência:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x

Comment: E no caso de um `input type="text"`, sabe como proceder ?

Comment: Não têm como colocar outros elementos dentro de um input, pode ser que ele esteja a utilizar alguma biblioteca que simule tags, como o Bootstrap Tags Input por exemplo.

Comment: Adicionei uma página de demonstração. http://b2bi.com.br/B2BI2017/app/demo.html